# How to change a Pentaho report's JNDI at runtime?

Tags: pentaho

I have a lot of Pentaho reports that were built in Pentaho Report Designer 3.8 and use JDBC.  I would like to set the data source's JNDI at runtime.  I tried accomplishing this using an Action Sequence (without SQLLookupRule) but the report keeps using the JNDI stored within the report.

Is there a way to do this?  I am really trying to avoid moving the SQL for every report into an xaction.